# How local variable issue is solved by catching exception by reference

Tags: c++, exception

In more effective c++ Item no -13, Item 13: Catch exceptions by reference.

Point also saying - To catch exception by pointer to work, programmers must  define exception object in a way that guarantees the object exist after control leave the function. Global and static objects work  fine.

// an example where catching exception by pointer

```
class exception { ... };          // from the standard C++

void someFunction()
{
    static exception ex;            // exception object
    ...
    throw &ex;                      // throw a pointer to ex
    ...
}
void doSomething()
{
    try 
    {
        someFunction();               // may throw an exception*
    }

    catch (exception *ex) 
    {    // catches the exception*;
        ...                           // no object is copied
    }
}
```

My doubt is how it differs in case of catching exception by reference? If it is a local variable (not static or global), then object don't exists once control leaves the function. then how issue is solved by catching exception by reference?

Answer (score 4):

To catch a pointer, you must throw a pointer. To catch a reference, you throw an object *by value*. A throw expression given the name of an object makes a copy of the object; it doesn't interpret its argument as a reference.

The thrown copy is called the *exception object* and it lives in a special allocation area maintained by the runtime library. Its destructor is called when exception propagation finishes, which might be anywhere up the call stack. C++11 provides additional tools to manually control exception object lifetime using reference-counting semantics.

If you catch by value, then another copy is made upon entering the `catch` block which catches by value, and this second copy is destroyed when leaving that `catch` block even if the exception propagates to another enclosing `catch` block. The outer `catch` would see the original exception object without any modifications applied by the inner `catch`.

The ability to let `catch` blocks communicate is realized by the idiom of catching by *non-`const`* reference.

---

By the way, throw by pointer is fundamentally broken because it cannot handle an out of memory error. If you try to allocate an exception object using `new` but there is no more memory, a `std::bad_alloc` will hijack the program before it gets to the `throw` expression. The library provides an alternative means of allocating exceptions to provide for out of memory conditions.

Comment: If i am not wrong, while we use call by reference, no copy is created. Is the behavior different in case of catch?

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal Catch by reference does not produce a copy. Catch by value, like pass by value, does produce a copy. There is no such thing as throw by reference; there is only throw by value.

Comment: In case of throw by value and catch by reference, no copy will be created, right? And as the value is local, so that will be destroyed, once we come out from the function.

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal Throw by value, like pass by value, does create a copy. The exception object is essentially a global.